# How do I store the whole iteration result?

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm having a problem in storing the whole results after iteration(for-loop).
I would like to save `prob0` for each i in `result_negative.append((' '.join(i), prob0))`.
However, only last `prob0` is saved from the first to last row. Does anyone know where I made a mistake?

```
result_negative = []
for i in result_te:
    prob0 = math.log(c0)
    for word in i:
        if word in set0[0]:
            prob0 = math.log(set0[set0[0] == word]['prob']) + prob0
        else :
            prob0 = math.log(1)+prob0
    
    result_negative.append((' '.join(i), prob0))
```

Edited)
I'm sorry. The values I got are not the results of iteration. it was the initial value, `prob0 = math.log(c0)`. Now I'm pretty confused

Comment: If you want every result from the inner loop to be saved, then you need to indent the `append` statement so it is part of the inner loop.  Right now, you only append after the inner loop is finished.

Comment: Your append needs to be inside the inner loop.

Comment: @FrankYellin Sorry, I think the values I obtained was `prob0=math.log(c0)`, which is not the  result of iteration, but the third line of the code.

Comment: @TimRoberts Sorry, I think the values I obtained was prob0=math.log(c0), which is not the result of iteration, but the third line of the code.

Comment: If `prob0` is not being updated, that suggests your inner loop is not being run.  Is `result_te` supposed to be a list of lists?

Comment: @TimRoberts Hi Tim, yes list and string data

Comment: Then your problem is not in your code.  It's in your data.  We would need to see your actual data to do any more.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
result_negative = []
for i in result_te:
    prob0 = math.log(c0)
    for word in i:
        if word in set0[0]:
            prob0 = math.log(set0[set0[0] == word]['prob']) + prob0
        else :
            prob0 = math.log(1)+prob0
            result_negative.append((' '.join(i), prob0)) #now this is inside the loop
```

Comment: Thanks but I made a mistake explaining my fault. The values I obtained was not a iteration result. It was the initial value, `prob0 = math.log(c0)`. Would you help me again?

Comment: Refer to the answer provided by @Nima, thank you Nima :)

Comment: It does not work :(

Comment: @user14261785 whta is your problem? why this is not work?

Comment: The problem is that only the initial value of prob0(math.log(c0)) shows up. That for-loop does not work to prob0.

Answer (score 1):

Like below, as @Tim Roberts and @Frank Yellin said, and @personaltest25's solution corrected:

```py
result_negative = []
for i in result_te:
    prob0 = math.log(c0)
    for word in i:
        if word in set0[0]:
            prob0 = math.log(set0[set0[0] == word]['prob']) + prob0
        else :
            prob0 = math.log(1)+prob0
        result_negative.append((' '.join(i), prob0))
```

Comment: Please share the full code so that I can run and debug it.

Comment: full code is pretty large...I don't understand why only initial prob0 shows up.

Comment: What about a few examples of result_te, c0, and set0?